# Execute QTest API from Azure Pipeline and update the report back to ADO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, qtest

how to execute Tricentis QTest from Azure pipeline and publish report back to pipeline result?
Do we have any QTest plugin available in azure? or Do we have any Qtest API to execute from pipeline task?

Comment: Hi @Sathiya, have you got a chance to check the answer below? If it could address your concerns, you may consider accepting the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there seems no such a build-in/extension task in Azure DevOps; however, this [demo](https://www.tricentis.com/resources/devops-workflows-qtest) by Tricents, helps us understand how to send webhook request via CMD/powershell tasks in a YAML pipeline to publish test reports.

According to the [document](https://www.tricentis.com/blog/azure-devops-qtest-integration) from Tricentis,

> We’ll walk through a new preview integration between Tricentis qTest and Azure DevOps Boards, then point you to more information on how to use qTest with Azure Pipelines.
>
> To integrate ADO Boards with qTest, we’ll be using the [qTest Pulse](https://www.tricentis.com/products/unified-test-management-qtest/agile-devops-workflows-pulse/) application. Pulse is a rules engine that automates tool communication, allowing teams to build and orchestrate custom DevOps workflows within their end-to-end pipeline. Many integrations and workflows for qTest are already available to our community for popular tools and frameworks, including Cucumber, Postman, and SonarQube on the [Tricentis GitHub repository](https://github.com/Tricentis/qTest.Integration.Pulse)

By the way, the integration task can be usually published by the service provider in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Installs)(not seems to publish yet as of now).

Hope the information could help and good luck.